# Distance to a rotating sloped cylinder

Tags: geometry

I am having trouble to derive the distance $x(\beta)$ of the sloped pink cylinder, when it rotates ($\beta$ is rotation angle). The slope angle is $\alpha$ ($\alpha=0$ if the cylinder is straight). It would be no problem to calculate this distance for a static situation, but I don't know how to handle the rotation - what happens there geometrically? Is it really as easy as varying the angle from $\alpha$ for $\beta=0°$ to $-\alpha$ for $\beta=180°$?

To explain the aim: a sensor is measuring the distance to a rotating slice (dimensions: diameter $d$, thickness $h$) and the incline is supposed to be a disturbance.

[image: Sketch]